# Make click on last element

Tags: c#, wpf, click

How to make click on last element?

Explanation : user click on button and move mouse in mode of click to another button. So click should be executed for last button, not for first one.

In WPF I have tried all possible events to get this (`MouseUp` seems to be right choice for this, but this doesn't do what I expect).

How to resolve this problem?

---

*UPD*: 2 Buttons in xaml:

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Click="ButtonThigh_OnClick" >
                        <Grid Width="150" Height="75">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=TrackingThighCircumference, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            <TextBlock MouseRightButtonDown="Thigh_EditStarted" Height="65" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                <TextBox Name="sizeThigh" Background="Transparent" Height="40" IsEnabled="False" ContextMenu="{x:Null}" ContextMenuService.IsEnabled="false" DataObject.Pasting="TextBox_Pasting" MaxLength="6" PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp" Tag="ThighCircumferenceUI" Text="{Binding Path=ThighCircumferenceUI, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
                                <LineBreak/>
                                <TextBlock Name="ThighLb" Text="{x:Static strings:Resource.Thigh}"/><Span>&#160;(</Span><Span><TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MeasurenentText, Path=Text}"/></Span><Span>)</Span>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Click="ButtonWaist_OnClick" >
                        <Grid Width="150" Height="75">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=TrackingJacketWaistCircumference, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" MouseRightButtonDown="Waist_EditStarted">
                                <TextBox Name="sizeWaist" Background="Transparent" Height="40" IsEnabled="False" ContextMenu="{x:Null}" ContextMenuService.IsEnabled="false" DataObject.Pasting="TextBox_Pasting" MaxLength="6" PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp" Tag="JacketWaistCircumferenceUI" Text="{Binding Path=JacketWaistCircumferenceUI, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
                                <LineBreak/>
                                <TextBlock Name="WaistLb" Text="{x:Static strings:Resource.Waist}"/><Span>&#160;(</Span><Span><TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MeasurenentText, Path=Text}"/></Span><Span>)</Span>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </Button>
```

Button Clicks :

```
private void ButtonThigh_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _resultViewModel.SelectMeasurement(si => si.ThighCircumference, vm => vm.ThighImg);
    }

    private void ButtonWaist_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _resultViewModel.SelectMeasurement(si => si.JacketWaistCircumference, vm => vm.WaistImg);
    }
```

Comment: @Moe, No, i haven't. Can you explaine a little bit more? Thanks

Comment: _MouseUp seems to be right choice for this, but this doesn't do what I expect_ why?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, I don't know, really, why it doesn't work. In case i Set MouseUp - nothing happens even if I just make a click on button. With PreviewMouseUp - better, but it works as default click (click fires for first button)

Comment: @galakt, if you talk about `MouseUp` - then yes. I have just tried it

Comment: `MouseUp` is not really a click. Clicking is a combination of `MouseDown` + `MouseUp` without moving mouse. `MouseDown` + moving is beginning of dragging (sometimes used to scroll). First button will capture mouse after `MouseDown` and it will receive `MouseUp` even if mouse if moved away, this is expected behavior. First button shouldn't rise any `Click` event. Is this a problem? Can you show xaml and related code?

Comment: @Sinatr, check code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it on buttons:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("1");
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("2");
    }

    private void Button1_OnPreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        button1_Click(sender,e);
    }
    private void Button2_OnPreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        button2_Click(sender,e);
    }

    private void Button1_OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    private void Button2_OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

After that, your PreviewMouseUp will work as you expect:
[image]

Comment: No, `PreviewMouseUp` didn't  work as I expect after this updates

Comment: @demo you did it on first-click button?

Comment: if i click and move - nothing happens. Only if i click and don't move click fires

Comment: @demo In my demo i do mouse_down on buton1, then move mouse to button2, then do mouse_up and action for button2 execute. Is it what you want?

Comment: @demo, *"if i click and move - nothing happens. Only if i click and don't move click fires"*  - this is how it suppose to work. And it is working this way, right? Now tell what you want and why? Why pressing button over first button, moving to second button and release button should trigger click for second button. Why?

Comment: @Sinatr, user click on button, then think - not this one, and move click to another button. So another button click must be fired

Comment: @demo, no way. Where have you seen user behaving like this? User do not changing his mind in a middle of click. User will click rather fast, clicking slowly is rather unusual. If action is dangerous - give a confirmation prior executing action (e.g. message box "are you sure want blablabla" Ok/Cancel).